# Sitecore 8 Reset Layout issue

Tags: templates, inheritance, sitecore, sitecore8

I need to add a rendering to all the pages. I thought adding to a Page Basic template that I have and is being inherited for all the page templates.
These page templates have different renderings and layout so the presentation is overridden. On top of that, authors have been adding more renderings to the pages themselves.

Any ideas on how to add this rendering to all the pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use sitecore Powershell to accomplish this. After traversing the tree you could add the rendering using the code in this link.

Just make sure to backup you db, just in case!

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/06/sitecore-powershell-add-rendering-to-item/

Comment: I could add to all the pages with a script but I'll need to add it every time I add a new page.. So I'm trying to add it at the template level. I